# Extensive filtering

Tags: mongodb, database

**Example:**

```js
{
    shortName: "KITT",
    longName: "Knight Industries Two Thousand",
    fromZeroToSixty: 2,
    year: 1982,
    manufacturer: "Pontiac", 

    /* 25 more fields */ 

}
```

- Ability to query by at least 20 fields which means that only 10 fields are left unindexed
- There's 3 fields (all number) that could be used for sorting (both ways)

---

This leaves me wondering that how does sites with lots of searchable fields do it: *e.g* real estate or car sale sites where you can filter by every small detail and can choose between several sort options.

**How could I pull this off with MongoDB?** How should I index that kind of collection?

Im aware that there are dbs specifically made for searching but there must be general rules of thumb to do this (even if less performant) in every db. Im sure not everybody uses Elasticsearch or similar.

### ---

*Optional reading:*

My reasoning is that index could be huge but the index order matters. You'll always make sure that fields that return the least results are first and most generic fields are last in index. However, what if user chooses only generic fields? Should I include non-generic fields to query anyway? How to solve ordering in both ways? Or index intersection saves the day and I should just add 20 different indexes?

Comment: Index intersection works for 2 indexes only. As a rule of thumb, look at faceted search implementations, if your data fits into it. Another rule of thumb is to describe the exact problem you are facing. Btw, why not ES? Just curious.

Comment: @AlexBlex Elasticsearch? It's a new thing for me and time is not on my side. I guess if I use Elasticsearch service from AWS and a Node.js client, I could learn it (more) quickly. Still, more moving parts for a project that I build alone.

Comment: Then don't bother about indexes until you actually have the performance issues. There is no such thing as future-proof optimisation in mongo.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for your advice. I was hoping to cover all my queries with indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text index` is your friend.

Read up on it here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/

In short, it's a way to tell `mongodb` that you want full text search over a specific field, multiple fields, or all fields (yay!)

To allow text indexing of all fields, use the special symbol `$**`, and define it of type 'text':

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

you can also configure it with `Case Insensitivity` or `Diacritic Insensitivity`, and more.

To perform text searches using the index, use the `$text` query helper, see: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text

**Update:**

In order to allow user to select specific fields to search on, it's possible to use weights when creating the text-index: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#specify-weights
If you carefully select your fields' weights, for example using different prime numbers only, and then add the [$meta](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/projection/meta/#proj._S_meta) text score to your results you may be able to figure out from the "textScore" which field was matched on this query, and so filter out the results that didn't get a hit from a selected search field.

Read more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/

Comment: That's nice, I've read about it. Im wondering if it could be deployed so that user has a set of inputs to choose from, instead of a single text input. Unfortunately users often don't know what exactly  they're looking for if you don't show them the options they can choose from.